# how do i get particular fields in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have two rows like below

```
Tp1g00130_scaffold_1    blastn    exon    20495    20602    .    +    .    
Tp1g00130_scaffold_1    blastn    exon    20650    20804    .    +    .
```

What i want to do is to merge the seq start (column 3 of row 1) and seq end (column 4 of row 2) of two lines if they have the same ID(column 1). For example, the output would look like

```
Tp1g00130_scaffold_1    blastn    exon    20495    20804    .    +    .
```

I made a good start but cannot quite finish.

```
prev = None

with open("test_parse") as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        line_id = line[0]
        print line
        if prev is not None and prev == line_id:
            print "yes"
        prev = line_id
```

Any help?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you merge non-overlapping exons you might create artificial exons.  What if they are actually two separate exons?

Comment: Good point. Let me think about it.

Comment: This is not for annotation purposes...

Comment: Are the seq start and stop rows always *right next to each other*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

Instead of `prev` being just the `id`, make it the whole last line. This lets us check existance and id (`if prev and prev[0] == line[0]:`) and get the seq start and seq end (`print('{} -> {}'.format(prev[3], line[4]))`).

```
prev = None
with open("test_parse") as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if prev and prev[0] == line[0]:
            print(' '.join(prev).replace(prev[4], line[4]).split())
        prev = line
```

Comment: Great. I have one question though. How do i join these two - `test = '{} {}'.format(prev[0:4], line[4:])`. I ask this because i am getting this output `['Tp1g00130_scaffold_1', 'blastn', 'exon', '20495'] ['20804', '.', '+', '.',]

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: rather than two lists which i am currently getting, i want one list only. For example - [Tp1g00130_scaffold_1', 'blastn', 'exon', '20495', '20804', '.', '+', '.']

Comment: See if that's what you want, @upendra. I got `['Tp1g00130_scaffold_1', 'blastn', 'exon', '20495', '20804', '.', '+', '.']` for output.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small you can use a temporary dict.

```
records = {}

with open("test_parse") as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        id_, f1, f2, start, end, f4, f5, f6 = line.strip().split()
        if id_ in records:
            records[id_][4] = end
        else:
            records[id_] = [id_, f1, f2, start, end, f4, f5, f6]

for line in records.values():
    print "\t".join(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a a header row in your file you can use a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

For a file with headers for columns x, y, and z you can do:

```
import DictReader

reader = DictReader(open('sample.csv'))
for line in reader:
    print(line['x'], line['z'])
```

The csv module it is a part of is very helpful in general.